# How to say among these things, I can only do this?

Tags: grammar

If I want to say, "Among the events written on the website, I can only come to the event on thursday," is this correct?

サイトに書いてあるイベントの中で、木曜日のイベントしか来られません。

Answer (score 2):

It sounds correct to me.

But I'd say サイトに書いてあるイベントの中で**は**、木曜日のイベントしか来られません。

It sounds more like the speaker is going to make a choice among the events. I can't explain why. But since I'm a native Japanese speaker, I don't think it's totally wrong.